# How to decode an Ethereum transaction input of an 0x transaction

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, 0x

The input data is very large. I believe there are multiple functions called.

Can I just hash each of the functions in the ABI, get the 6 characters and compare them to the first six characters of the data. Then get the inputs and match them to the next characters in the data. Then just remove the matched characters and start the process all over again to find the next function and parameters?

Do I need to transform the input data at all? I haven't had much success with the mentioned process yet, so I assumed maybe I am missing something there.

Another issue is that the 0x contract has multiple different ABIs. Can I just combine them into one array if there are no conflicting functions names? Or even if I know the functions needed just keep those in a created ABI?

Also I want to do this in PHP, I have found other libraries in JS and python that I can't use for this project but can use for reference. I need some help with these questions to help move me forward.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the combined ABI from etherescan. different sol files did not mean different ABIs.

There also is and can only be one function call. The other data I was looking for were in the event logs.